# How do I edit and repackage the source code of a RPM?

Tags: build, development-environment, patch, rpm, rpmbuild

The title of this question does not begin to capture my years of exasperation with the RPM system.  There is a vast gulf between a development system (./configure; make; make install;) and a rpm system (tar files, patch files, spec files, arcane build scripts, environments and tools) which I cannot bridge.

All I want to do is to change a few lines of code in a bigger program.

The problems which I run into:

1. Getting the source code of the system as-installed (e.g. SRPM from EPEL, original tarball, something else).  What source should I use?
2. Getting that source code into a ready-to-edit form - something that I can edit with my favourite editor.  How can I know that I'm editing the code as-deployed, bugs and all?  (rpm -ivh x.src.rpm gives me tar files and squabs of patch files littered about in the SOURCES directory ... how can I get it right?)
3. Editing the code to implement some amazing hack (this part I can actually do).
4. Compiling the amazing code as edited - just compiling it in-place.  Usually I can get this right, but it would be nice to have a hand sometimes, e.g. with ./configure set to use something other than the default /usr/local and /lost+found/opt/etc/opt or whatever crazy default autoconf decides to use.
5. Transforming my edits into a patch against the previous source and building new RPMs to test on some remote system (this is the great promise of RPM - pristine sources and hacky patches).  If I do a diff of the original and the edited directories, the resulting patch contains all sorts of rubbish that I don't want to delete because I'm still developing (e.g. object code).  (Actually, I don't have an 'original' at this point to do a diff against ... because I was only looking at the code casually when I realised I could "improve" it ...)  Should I use some revision control system to track the changes I am making?

This should be simple stuff, but somehow all I can do is edit the code.  After I have edited the code, it can never get over the hump, even though it is an already-solved problem.  I have a GREAT fix for an open source project, but every single time that I finish developing my amazing hack, having delved into the code and made it compile (and possibly work), I am completely stumped.  Nothing at all can turn my modified and now amazing source tree into a RPM.  I end up deploying source code (into /usr/local), because that at least works.

How do people who do (say) security fixes actually go about the extract-edit-compile-test loop?

Comment: I can't seem to see a clear question. Have you followed the documentation? https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM should get you started. And it refers to http://www.owlriver.com/tips/patching_srpms/ which describes your exact problem.

Comment: Those are good links, but seriously, is that as good as it gets?  owlriver.com link has this as part of the testing — `./configure --sysconfdir=/etc/joe` — which exactly illustrates the problem.  Is re-engineering almost everything that is already in the srpm file unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

The SRPM is (relatively) self-contained: there are often some assumptions about build requirements not reflected in the spec file.

- I would start by taking the SRPM, and rebuilding it to address the issue of build-requirements (adding whatever is needed to get it to build).
- Then, extract the spec-file and sources from the SRPM, putting the patches and tar-file(s) into `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES`, and building from the spec-file
- Next, modify the spec-file to add my *own* patch file (or scripting changes),
- Finally there's a new SRPM with my changes.

For extracting, I use an `unrpm` script (essentially a wrapper around `cpio`) which can be [found](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/examples/unrpm) on the network.

Making your own patch file is discussed here:

- [HowTo Create A Patch File For A RPM](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/HowTo_Create_A_Patch_File_For_A_RPM)
- [RPM - Creating Patches](http://www.adempiere.com/RPM_-_Creating_Patches)
- [Patches for .spec file](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/patches-for-spec-file-145237/)

Comment: This won't do - I need to edit the code - the `c` and `cc` files.  I am _making_ a patch, not applying a pre-packaged patch.  Apart from this, the **how** is not a trivial matter, with the RPM system happy to delete away my changes when I say the wrong thing.

Comment: That's in "modify the spec-file", etc. (really).  I added a few links to help.

Comment: The links kind of say "this sucks" in various ways, and "works great for simple cases", e.g. ""Be careful not to actually compile the code!" (it deletes your changes) and "Get A Base Copy Of The Original Source Tree", which rather assumes that the original source tree is in a usable format.  For many projects this is simply not the case.  I don't want to edit the original in the land of `/usr/local/etc`, and then compile for Linux ...